# Re-writing EXISTS as JOIN or a subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, exists

I have a query which is very costly and taking more than an hour to execute. I tried converting the EXISTS clause to join but I am stuck, can anyone help?

The purpose is to find duplicate product within a unique space id. `FLAT_TABLE` consists of 5 million records.

Query:

```
 select
    tbl1.product,
    tbl1.status,
    tbl1.reservation,
    tbl1.unique_space_id
FROM
    schema1.flat_table tbl1
WHERE
    tbl1.status = 'Active'
    AND tbl1.product = 'Cage'
    AND EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
        FROM schema1.flat_table tbl2
        WHERE tbl2.product = 'Cage'
        AND tbl2.status = 'Active'
        AND tbl2.reservation <> 'Space Reserved'
        AND tbl1.unique_space_id = tbl2.unique_space_id
        GROUP BY tbl2.unique_space_id
        HAVING COUNT (1) > 1
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your query as an inner join to the current exists subquery.  The join would have the effect of filtering in the same way the exists clause was behaving.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbl1.product,
    tbl1.status,
    tbl1.reservation,
    tbl1.unique_space_id
FROM schema1.flat_table tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT unique_space_id
    FROM schema1.flat_table
    WHERE product = 'Cage' AND
          status = 'Active' AND
          reservation <> 'Space Reserved'
    GROUP BY unique_space_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) tbl2
    ON tbl2.unique_space_id = tbl1.unique_space_id
WHERE
    tbl1.status = 'Active' AND
    tbl1.product = 'Cage';
```

Here is a more concise version using `COUNT` as an analytic function, along with a `QUALIFY` clause;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT product, status, reservation, unique_space_id
FROM schema1.flat_table
WHERE status = 'Active' AND product = 'Cage'
QUALIFY COUNT(CASE WHEN reservation <> 'Space Reserved' THEN 1 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY unique_space_id) > 1;
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. :-)

Comment: I am very new to stack overflow and have less than 15 reputations so actually my vote won't add a green checkmark. However I have upvoted which is recorded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use analytical function `count` as follows:

```
select * from
(select tbl1.product, tbl1.status, tbl1.reservation, tbl1.unique_space_id,
        count(case when tbl1.reservation <> 'Space Reserved' then 1 end) 
         over(partition by tbl1.unique_space_id) as cnt 
  FROM schema1.flat_table tbl1  
 WHERE tbl1.status = 'Active' AND tbl1.product = 'Cage')
 where cnt > 1
```

Comment: This really works, thanks. But i would like avoid analytical functions as of now. Inner join suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen works just fine.

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped you. :)

Comment: @MohammedArif . . . Why would you want to avoid window functions.  They are more concise and almost always have better performance than  alternatives.